# Handle error if iframe src gives 404 Error in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

I have an iframe and I'm loading different pages in iframe with dynamic src. Some of the src exists while other doesn't exist and gives 404 Error.

```
<iframe  [src]="getSource() | safe"></iframe>
```

getsource() function returns link to html page.
Please guide me for this. I am looking for javascript or Angular ways of doing this.